# How did early childhood baptisms started in Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism, history, baptism

Jesus got baptized at an age old enough to decide for himself.

Today, I always see infants getting baptized. According to Catholicism, when, where and how did early childhood (infant) baptisms got started?

Was there a mandate from the Vatican that imposes infants need to be baptized as soon as possible?

Answer (score 2):

The earliest recorded instance of child baptism is in the Acts of the Apostles when Lydia, *a seller of purple of the city of Thyatira* was baptized along with *her household* (Acts 16:14).  Other instances of child baptism recorded in the New Testament are in Acts 16:33, Acts 18:8, and 1 Corinthians 1:16.

This is all in accordance with the commandment given by Peter that all, including children, *be baptized in the name of Jesus Christ for the remission of sins* (Acts 2:38-39).

Comment: Good answer, an improvement would be to include if there were ever instances in the history of the Catholic Church where infant baptism was _not_ the norm.   And, also a specific Catholic apologetic that references these Bible verses as pertaining to infant baptism.  (for instance, the Textual Concordance of Scripture published by TAN refers to your references in Acts and 1 Corinthians a _probably inferring_ infant baptism).

Comment: The New Testament itself is, in fact, a document of the Church.  Acts in particular dates to a period long before the See of Rome and the other Sees of the Church separated at the Great Schism.